# VBA: Using an array, how can I exclude criteria based on part of a string when filtering a column

Tags: arrays, vba, filter

so I'm fairly new to VBA, and I was trying to use an array to filter out unwanted criteria from a worksheet. The problem I'm having is that there's more than 2 criteria, and the criteria I want to filter out aren't fully known as the report I'm filtering changes on a daily basis.

However, the common denominator of the items I want to filter out, is they will contain either the word "project" or "problem-mgmt" e.g. "Test1-project", "Test72-problem-mgmt". I was wondering if it would be at all possible to filter out criteria based on part of a cell value (e.g. "project") when using an array? The code I'm using is listed below, which works fine when I know the exact name of each value I want to filter. The list of criteria to be filtered are in column K.

```
        Dim filterCriteria() As String
        Dim count As Long, secondArray As Variant
        Dim L As Long, c As String, k As String, rowNumb As Long

        secondArray = Array("test-in-flight", "test-project", "test-problem-mgmt") ' State list of queues to exclude.

        c = 0
        k = 0
        count = 0
        rowNumb = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("K2"), ActiveSheet.Range("K1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

            For L = 1 To rowNumb
                c = ActiveSheet.Range("K1").Offset(L)
                If c <> k Then

                    If UBound(Filter(secondArray, c)) = -1 Then ' Check the current list against the array of items to exclude.
                        ReDim Preserve filterCriteria(0 To count) ' If it isn’t in the array, it's added to an array that will be used as the filter criteria.
                        filterCriteria(count) = c
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                    k = c
                End If

        Next

        With ActiveSheet
            .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 13)).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=filterCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' Apply filter criteria stored above.
        End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only two patterns with wild-card, `Range.AutoFilter` is enough since it allows for two wildcard criteria (but not more). This looks straightforward:

```
With ActiveSheet
  .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 13)).AutoFilter Field:=11, _
    Criteria1:="<>*project", Criteria2:="<>*problem-mgmt", Operator:=xlAnd
End With
```

However if you have more than two such criteria, `Advanced Filter` is the way to go. Take a look at [this excellent tutorial](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html) on advanced filters.